# Weird Lag Bug with Internet Explorer 9 + Silverlight 4 + MVVM Light 

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, mvvm-light, internet-explorer-9

I have a very weird bug when I try to debug when my silverlight application run under Internet Explorer 9 (RC). I use MVVM Light framework. (And I use a WCF WebService, but I guess this part isn't a issue)

I have two *side effects/bugs*:

1. When a breakpoint is hit and I pres F5, I have at least 5-8 sec of wait.(no reason).
2. Sometimes when I move my mouse anywhere my pc beeps (many short beeps) and my mouse moves very very slowly.

I run the same this on chrome or firefox without any problems.

I use MVVM Light Toolkit V3 SP1 (4).

Answer (score 0):

Mb this http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/workitem/7293 ?

Well anyway it seem that there is some "memory leek" or something like that... it dosen't crush IE but it gives a lot of trobles..

Try this. Create new empty project and try to add onle feature after another (one by one)... maybe this will help you to find where problem is..

Answer (score 0):

I create a very small sample of this behaviour...

http://cid-9292b3e7504f952f.office.live.com/self.aspx/Public/MVVM%20Bug/MVVM%20Light%20Test%201.zip

Put beakpoint on this line ...

```
//TEST PUT Breakpoint here !!!!!!!!! each F10 take 3-5 sec ...
ListOfSample.Clear();
```